# Subquery Building a Column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing the following query.

```
SELECT 
t.iCertification_UserCertificationTranscriptID  AS I_CERT_TRANSCRIPT_DIM, 
t.iHR_UserID                                    AS I_EMP_DIM, 
t.iCertification_CertificationID                AS I_RUL_CERT_DIM,
(
    SELECT iHR_PositionID
    FROM UserProfileNoGroups AS prof
    WHERE 
        (iHR_UserID = t.iHR_UserID) 
        AND (Profile_IsPrimary = '1') 
        AND (UserPosition_IsPrimary = '1') 
        AND (t.dEffectiveStart BETWEEN UserPosition_Effective AND COALESCE(UserPosition_End, LOCALTIMESTAMP))
    ORDER BY UserPosition_Effective DESC
    FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
) AS I_POSN_DIM,                                    
CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t.dEffectiveStart) * 10000 + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM t.dEffectiveStart) * 100 + EXTRACT(DAY FROM t.dEffectiveStart) AS INT)   AS I_DAY_STRT_DIM, 
CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t.dEffectiveEnd) * 10000 + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM t.dEffectiveEnd) * 100 + EXTRACT(DAY FROM t.dEffectiveEnd) AS INT)         AS I_DAY_END_DIM,  
CASE 
    WHEN t.iCertification_TranscriptSourceID = '1' THEN 'Y' 
    ELSE 'N' 
END                                     AS L_AdminOverride,
t.mComment                          AS X_Comment
FROM 
dbo.tCertification_UCT AS t;
```

I am concerned of the query that builds column I_POSN_DIM. The query performs slowly and it seems like that query has to be scanned over and over to extract results. This is in postgresql and I am not that familiar with this platform. I tried using CTEs that uses the MAX function, but the COUNT always turns out different from this query. Any assistance would be appreaciated.

Comment: What results do you get when you run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE your query`?

Comment: I ran the query with EXPLAIN ANALYZE and it's still running after a half hour. I did it again, but ended the query with FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY. It returned results, but I doubt those results will be of any uses since it was pulling only a 100 rows.

Answer (score 0):

I thought something like this:

```
SELECT 
t.iCertification_UserCertificationTranscriptID  AS I_CERT_TRANSCRIPT_DIM, 
t.iHR_UserID                                    AS I_EMP_DIM, 
t.iCertification_CertificationID                AS I_RUL_CERT_DIM,
uPG.iHR_PositionID                              AS I_POSN_DIM,                                    
(t.dEffectiveStart.Year * 10000 + t.dEffectiveStart.Month * 100 +  t.dEffectiveStart.Day)   AS I_DAY_STRT_DIM, 
(t.dEffectiveEnd.Year * 10000 + t.dEffectiveEnd.Month * 100 + t.dEffectiveEnd.Day)         AS I_DAY_END_DIM,  
CASE WHEN t.iCertification_TranscriptSourceID = '1' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END                                                                       AS L_AdminOverride,
t.mComment                                      AS X_Comment
FROM dbo.tCertification_UCT AS t
INNER JOIN UserProfileNoGroups uPG ON t.iHR_UserID = uPG.iHR_UserID
WHERE Profile_IsPrimary = '1'
        AND UserPosition_IsPrimary = '1'
        AND (t.dEffectiveStart BETWEEN UserPosition_Effective AND COALESCE(UserPosition_End, LOCALTIMESTAMP));
```

I moved the inner query to outside and I convert it in an equivalent inner join. In others fields you did cast but it's not neccesary because of the result from that operations is an int.

But I supossed that table UserProfileNoGroups has 1 record for each record at tCertification_UCT. If it's not this way, the query would change a litlle:

```
SELECT 
t.iCertification_UserCertificationTranscriptID  AS I_CERT_TRANSCRIPT_DIM, 
t.iHR_UserID                                    AS I_EMP_DIM, 
t.iCertification_CertificationID                AS I_RUL_CERT_DIM,
uPG.iHR_PositionID  OVER (ORDER BY UserPosition_Effective DESC)                         AS I_POSN_DIM,                                    
(t.dEffectiveStart.Year * 10000 + t.dEffectiveStart.Month * 100 +  t.dEffectiveStart.Day)   AS I_DAY_STRT_DIM, 
(t.dEffectiveEnd.Year * 10000 + t.dEffectiveEnd.Month * 100 + t.dEffectiveEnd.Day)         AS I_DAY_END_DIM,  
CASE WHEN t.iCertification_TranscriptSourceID = '1' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END                              AS L_AdminOverride,
t.mComment                                      AS X_Comment
FROM dbo.tCertification_UCT AS t
INNER JOIN UserProfileNoGroups uPG ON t.iHR_UserID = uPG.iHR_UserID
WHERE Profile_IsPrimary = '1'
        AND UserPosition_IsPrimary = '1'
        AND (t.dEffectiveStart BETWEEN UserPosition_Effective AND COALESCE(UserPosition_End, LOCALTIMESTAMP));
```

You can play with OVER clause:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-window.html